# homeomorphism of cantor set extends to the plane?

Tags: general-topology, descriptive-set-theory, knot-theory

Suppose C is a Cantor set in the Euclidean plane, or even in R^3. Suppose h is a homeomorphism of C onto itself. Can h be extended to a homeomorphism of the whole space? What about if h preserves the ´end points´ of the Cantor set? Seems that the latter is a necessary condition but I don´t know how to prove it.

Answer (score 8):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$, Schonflies theorem ensures that any two embeddings of Cantor sets are equivalently embedded, or equivalently that any homeomorphism $h$ between the two Cantor sets (it can be proven that any two Cantor sets have a homeomorphism between them - I think this is proven in Edwin E. Moise's book *Geometric Topology in Dimensions 2 and 3*) can be extended to a homeomorphism $H \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

In $\mathbb{R}^3$, we have many examples of *rigid* Cantor sets; a personal favourite is [the following paper](https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/craigg/www/11%20-%20Dennis%20Garity,%20Dusan%20Repovs,%20Matjaz%20Zeljko.pdf) which generalises Skora's construction of a wildly embedded Cantor set in $S^3$ with a simply connected complement, to produce a rigid wildly embedded Cantor set in $\mathbb{R}^3$, with a simply connected complement.

Comment: Clarification: The proof that there is a homeomorphism between any two Cantor sets was given by Brouwer in 1909 ("On the structure of perfect sets of points", found at the publisher's site: http://www.dwc.knaw.nl/DL/publications/PU00013496.pdf).  Moise's text proves that if both are planar then the homeomorphism extends to the plane.

Comment: Do you know if exist any generalization of the Moise result to closed surface instead of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Answer (score 6):

This depends on what you want to call a Cantor set. The usual middle-thirds Cantor set is one embedding of the cantor set into the plane/$3$-space, however there are many other ways of embedding the Cantor set into a space and there appears to be a rich theory behind all the possible ways (I don't work in this area so I can't give too many details).

The paper [Homogeneity groups of ends of open $3$-manifolds](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.8109.pdf), Garity & Repovs, offers a brief glimpse of some of the questions that can arise, and you can get a feel for how non-trivial some of these embeddings can be by reading the introduction.

The standard middle thirds Cantor set embedding in the plane is known to be *strongly homeogenously embedded* which means any automorphism extends to the whole of the plane. However, on the other end of things there exist embeddings of the Cantor set in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that no non-trivial automorphism of the Cantor set can be extended - these are called *rigidly embedded*.

There are many [open problems](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XdXnQCV5K08C&pg=PA675&lpg=PA675&dq=cantor+set+%22extends+to+a+homeomorphism%22&source=bl&ots=CHDt_42fZ1&sig=qTGl8Hf3RopE6l8BSnQ8vu1owjs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=GP0xU9apKaPA7AblzoCQDA&ved=0CDEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=cantor%20set%20%22extends%20to%20a%20homeomorphism%22&f=false) related to these terms involving tame and wild embeddings in Eucldiean space.

Comment: Very interesting reference. Thank you!