# The remainder of a Cantor set in the plane

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, cantor-set

Assume  That $M$  is  a  compact  subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ which has zero measure and is homeomorphic to the Cantor  set:

Is the topology or  homology of $\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus M$  independent of $M$. We have the same question for the relative homology $H_{*}(\mathbb{R^{2}},\mathbb{R}^{2} \setminus M )$?

Comment: As $C$ is homeomorphic to two disjoint copies of $C$, or any finite union for that matter, I would assume that the complement in the plane of one or two disjoint copies would be different, at least in homology. But I cannot prove this yet.

Comment: You may find this question helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/726712/homeomorphism-of-cantor-set-extends-to-the-plane

Answer (score 2):

Non-compact surfaces without boundary are completely classified; see [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/21218/40804). Then the only relevant data to the homeomorphism type of $\mathbb R^2 \setminus M$ is its space of ends. I claim this is $M \sqcup \{\infty\}$.

This follows because the end *compactification* of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus M$ is $S^2$. All one needs to do, roughly, is verify that each of the points in $M$ (and $\infty$) is an end of $\Bbb R^2 \setminus M$. This follows then because $M$ is totally disconnected.